# Ajax post request is not functioning

Tags: php, ajax

I don't understand why my ajax did not returning any value after post. I am displaying count of registered user in a html table and allowing admin to click each of the count to see list of user name.

My html displaying count of registered user :

```
$sql2 = "SELECT COUNT(*) AS count FROM reg WHERE reg_id = '".$row['reg_id']."'";
$result2 = $conn->query($sql2);

if ($result2->num_rows > 0) {
    while($row2 = $result2->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo '<a class="slot" data-slotid='.$row['reg_id'].' href="">'.$row2['count'].'</a>';
    }
}

$sql2 = NULL;
```

Ajax request :

```
$('.slot').on('click', function(){
    var slotid = $(this).data('slotid');
    $.ajax ({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'my-domain.com/ajax-request',
        data: { slotid : slotid },
        success : function(htmlresponse) {
            $('#user_list').html(htmlresponse);
            console.log(htmlresponse);
        }
    });
});
```

My php function from another file to filter database row :

```
if(isset($_POST['slotid'])){
    // Mysql SELECT statement and echo query result
}
```

If I place a `alert(slotid)` right after `var slotid = $(this).data('slotid');` in the ajax function, it will display the correct value for each of the clicked link. But when I try to `echo $_POST['slotid'];` at php side, there is not value returned. It seems like the whole page is refreshing.

Comment: `"It seems like the whole page is refreshing."` - Well, is it?  You might remove the `href` from the `a` element entirely, I suspect an empty `href` may be interpreted as a link to the current page.  Or use something other than an `a`, something which doesn't have a default behavior for its click event.  Or probably a button, since the action you're performing seems to be button-like.

Comment: @David I didn't know that the `href` will affect the post. By the way, I've removed the `href` and it's working now. Thank you

Comment: `url: 'my-domain.com/ajax-request',` are you posting to a directory?

Comment: `$('.slot').on('click', function(event){ event.preventDefault(); //...etc` use this, otherwise the link will behave like a normal standard hyperlink, i.e. it will navigate to the URL given in the href instead of running the ajax request. Or, if the ajax request managed to begin before the page refreshes, it will then get cancelled as soon as the browser leaves the current page. See https://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/ for more.

Comment: P.S. Your code is vulnerable to SQL injection attacks. You should use parameterised queries and prepared statements to help prevent attackers from compromising your database by using malicious input values. http://bobby-tables.com/ gives an explanation of the risks, as well as some examples of how to write your queries safely using PHP / mysqli.

Comment: @GrumpyCrouton there are all sorts of ways to get extension-less URLs like this to work. Once we remove the default refresh behaviour, if the ajax call returns an error like 404, at that point we can suspect a dodgy URL. Up to now, there's no particular evidence for that being the case.

Comment: @ADyson I know, that's basically what I was asking, just to cover bases :)